# how does python class specical method work?

Tags: python, class, methods

I have a Cell class

```
class Cell :
    def __init__(self,char):
        self.char=char
        self.image='_'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.image == other.image

    def __ne__(self,other):
        return not self.image == other.image
```

then I have two Cell objects a and b, why I can use expression like "if a != b:" to compare these two object. How does b get inside of a and call the **eq** method to make the comparison

Answer (score 1):

`b` doesn't get inside.  When an operator is used, Python first looks for the magic method on the left-hand argument.  If the appropriate magic method is defined there, it is called.  If it doesn't return NotImplemented, then that's the result.  If the method doesn't exist (or it returns NotImplemented), then the magic method is called on the right-hand argument.  (For arithmetic operators, the right-hand arguments gets a separate method, `__radd__` being the right-hand version pf `__add__`, `__rsub__` for `__sub__`, etc.).

So in your version, it calls `__ne__` on `a` and that's it.  The magic method is never called on `b`.

This behavior is described in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

Answer (score 0):

Saying `if a == b` is equivalent to `if a.__eq__(b)`.

Likewise, saying `if a != b` is really `if a.__ne__(b)`. Both methods return boolean values.

Each class inherits default special methods for comparing equality and inequality, but these can be overridden if explicitly defined.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are the proper answer.

I just wanted to mention that `__ne__` has a bug related to precedence. It should be defined as:

`return not (self.image == other.image)`

Which is best expressed as:

`return not (self == other)`

[Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).